# IE 11 WMV video leaving black box on navigation

Tags: jquery, dom, internet-explorer-11, wmv, ie11-developer-tools

I have an existing application which uses WMV video content. As of 2019, this only works in IE 11, because Chrome doesn't support plugins any more. There are couple of videos which load on navigation and issue is as follows:
**Scenario 1:**
1. Play the video and navigate to next page
2. A black box size of the video is left out and it can't be debugged in Developer Tools, its dangling black box, without any markup and Developer tools aren't able to select it.

[image]
**Scenario 2:**
1. Don't play the video and navigate to next page
2. Everything works as expected, no black box, but you can't consume the video content

**Scenario 3:**
1. In the Object tag of WMV video, if I use DISPLAYCONTROLS property, which ends up giving the default controls(screenshot below), then there is no black box issue.

[image]

**Expected result:**
I need to make Scenario 1 working, where I don't have default controls displayed.

**Sample html markup:**

```
<div id="mc08632483328809373"><object width="400" height="300" class="objectouter" id="mcobject0.20815833798721461"
    classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="http://192.168.1.10:8080/external/10/Ears.wmv">
    <PARAM NAME="rate" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="balance" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="currentPosition" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="defaultFrame" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="playCount" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="autoStart" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="currentMarker" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="invokeURLs" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="baseURL" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="volume" VALUE="50">
    <PARAM NAME="mute" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="uiMode" VALUE="none">
    <PARAM NAME="stretchToFit" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="windowlessVideo" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="enabled" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="enableContextMenu" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="fullScreen" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMIStyle" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMILang" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMIFilename" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="captioningID" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="enableErrorDialogs" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="10583">
    <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="7938">
    <param name="ext" value="wmv">
    <param name="MOVIE" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
    <param name="AUTOSTART" value="false">
    <param name="data" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
    <param name="src" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
    <param name="WINDOWLESSVIDEO" value="1">
    <param name="ALT" value="">
    <param name="id" value="WM_0.09200819067981891">
    <param name="DISPLAYCONTROL" value="false">
    <param name="Controller" value="false">
    <param name="url" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
    <param name="base" value="../external/10/">
    <!--[if IE ]><!-- [endif]  -->
    <!-- [if !IE]  --><object width="400" height="300" class="objectinner" data="../external/10/Ears.wmv" type="application/x-ms-wmp"
        alt="" autostart="false" ext="wmv" displaycontrol="false" movie="../external/10/Ears.wmv" src="../external/10/Ears.wmv"
        controller="false" base="../external/10/">
        <param name="ext" value="wmv">
        <param name="MOVIE" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
        <param name="data" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
        <param name="AUTOSTART" value="false">
        <param name="src" value="../external/10/Ears.wmv">
        <param name="ALT" value="">
        <param name="DISPLAYCONTROL" value="false">
        <param name="Controller" value="false">
        <param name="type" value="application/x-ms-wmp">
        <param name="base" value="../external/10/"></object><!-- [endif]  --></object></div>
```

**What I have tried:**
1. Markup is getting updated using jquery remove and html methods. Object doesn't have remove method, thus tried with adding polyfill method from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove
Status: Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your code and I find that you had inserted so many parameters.

I suggest you to only use the required parameters as er your requirements instead of using so many parameters.

I try to remove them one by one and I find that below parameter causing this issue.

```
 <PARAM NAME="uiMode" VALUE="none">
```

I try to remove it and now video is playing in IE 11.

Tested Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<object width="400" height="300" class="objectouter" id="mcobject0.20815833798721461"
    classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Video1.wmv">


 <PARAM NAME="rate" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="balance" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="currentPosition" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="defaultFrame" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="playCount" VALUE="1">
    <PARAM NAME="autoStart" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="currentMarker" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="invokeURLs" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="baseURL" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="volume" VALUE="50">
    <PARAM NAME="mute" VALUE="0">

    <PARAM NAME="stretchToFit" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="windowlessVideo" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="enabled" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="enableContextMenu" VALUE="-1">
    <PARAM NAME="fullScreen" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMIStyle" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMILang" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="SAMIFilename" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="captioningID" VALUE="">
    <PARAM NAME="enableErrorDialogs" VALUE="0">
    <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="10583">
    <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="7938">
    <param name="ext" value="wmv">
    <param name="AUTOSTART" value="false">
    <param name="WINDOWLESSVIDEO" value="1">
    <param name="ALT" value="">
    <param name="id" value="WM_0.09200819067981891">
    <param name="DISPLAYCONTROL" value="false">
   </object>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Deepak. The parameters are generated from a legacy system, thus I can't change reduce the count, I am able to change the property value. In scenario 3, i.e. with video controls everything works as expected. The issue appears when you have one then one video and no controls, then when navigating the black box remains on the screen, which blocks the viewing area of next video.

Comment: Can you try to set AUTOSTART=true and check whether it helps or not. On my side it is playing the video with no controls and I had also added the <PARAM NAME="uiMode" VALUE="none"> line.